# CSS Flipper - iOS / Safari Issue

Tags: css, safari

I have a web page that emulates a wizard. After the user leaves the second step to go to the third step, I'm "flipping" the panel like a card. You can see it in action in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/K8sqaUonem). The code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#eee;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flip-container" style="width:200px;">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
          <div class="step-2-default" id="step2" style="overflow-x:hidden; padding:0.0rem 1.0rem;">
            <label>Step 2</label>
            <p>These are the details of the second step</p>
            <button id="nextButton2">next</button>        
          </div>

          <div class="step-1-default" id="step1">
            <label>Step 1</label>
            <p>These are the details of the first step</p>
            <button id="nextButton1">next</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="back">
          <div id="step3">
            <label>Step 3</label>
            <p>Thank you for using this wizard</p>
          </div>                                
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you load the Bootply, you'll notice that the step is visible from steps 1 and 2. From my understanding, the issue is the `height:auto` property. I'm using this because the size of the content for each of the steps in my wizard is dynamic.

It works fine in Chrome. But, I can't figure out how to make it work in iOS / Safari. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify this : "you'll notice that the step is visible from steps 1 and 2"

Comment: @Ced Please look at the Bootply in Safari. You'll see that the content in step3 "shows through". If you were looking at a playing card, you wouldn't want to see through the card. But, that's what's happening in this Bootply. That you for your interest in helping on this question.

Comment: To clarify, is your question how to get this to work completely in Safari and iOS or to keep the content from showing through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a webkit-specific `backface-visibility`:

```
.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/RiX9HF5t21

Answer (score 1):

That works for me in Safari (tested), just change the `background-color:transparent;` to `background-color: #fff;` for classes `.step-1-default`, `.step-2-default` and add:

```
.flip-container.flip .front {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I copy-and-pasted that line into the Bootply I posted. However, it did not work in Safari (or on iOS)

Comment: Did you change the `background-color: transparent` to `background-color: #fff` for class `.step-1-default` and `.step-2-default` ?

Comment: I did make those changes without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the other side from being visible in Safari & iOS, set the background color on the `front` and `back` classes:

```
.front, .back {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```